# How to filter product collection with configurable product attributes

Tags: filter, product-collection, collection-filtering, dropdown-attribute

Now I'm trying to filter product collections with my configurable product attribute i.e ***size***

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
              ->getCollection()
              ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
              ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility','4')
              ->addAttributeToFilter('size','3');
```

Above code doesn't works. Apart from attribute **size** i can able to filter this collection with any attributes like ***name, sku, created_date etc.***

Did anyone know where i'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out by myself.

Above code returns nothing because attribute (**size**) is assigned only to simple products (associated products) and all simple product's **visibility is set to 1** i.e, **not visible individually.**

**Step 1 :** Remove visibility to 1, now i can get list of all simple products (associated products) which is assigned to size 3.

**Step 2 :** Join table **catalog_product_super_link** to get parent product associated with it.

Complete code is,

```
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToFilter(
            array(
            array('attribute'=> 'color','like' => '12')
            )
        )
        // multiple filters can be achieved by adding another filterattribute
        ->addAttributeToFilter(
            array(
            array('attribute'=> 'size','like' => '3')
            )
        );

   $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('link_table' => 'catalog_product_super_link'),'link_table.product_id = e.entity_id',
            array('product_id','parent_id')
        );

   $collection->getSelect()->group('link_table.parent_id');

   foreach($collection as $product) {
        $ids[] = $product->getParentId();
       }

    $collection->load();

    echo json_encode($ids);
```

Hope this may help to someone.

Comment: `visibility = 4` was very tricky :) as the associated products have `visibility = 1`

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
$filter = array(
    'attribute' => 'size',
    'in'        => array(3),
    );

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
          ->getCollection()
          ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
          //->addAttributeToFilter('visibility',4)
          ->addAttributeToFilter($filter);
```

Haven't tested, but should work. Hope this helps.
[Ref.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24081453/get-the-products-collection-filter-by-attributes-with-array-of-values)

Comment: Not working for me. Using above code in Magento 1.9.1.0, I am getting the following error: `Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 816`

Comment: Can you try with removing `' '` for numbers.

Comment: Did that. Same error.

Answer (score 1):

`visibility = 4` made it tricky. Commented it out and `size` filter worked fine.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
              ->getCollection()
              ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
              //->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', '4')
              ->addAttributeToFilter('size', array('3', '4')); // 3, 4 are attribute's option_id
```